# Set OnClickListener on CardView using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an Android app and my app has 4 Activities. I am using `CardView` for switching the Activity. I want it so that when the user clicks the `CardView` the user will go to the targeted Activity.

The problem is I am using #Kotlin and I can't set `CardView#OnClickListener`
using Kotlin. How can I set the `OnClickListener` using Kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
cardView.setOnClickListener{
        //Access view by using `it`
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize this in `onCreate` of the  activity.

```
CardViewId.setOnClickListener(clickListener)
```

Add this code snippet as a method anywhere in your activity:

```
   private val clickListener: View.OnClickListener = View.OnClickListener { view ->
        when (view.id) {
            R.id.CardViewId -> gotoXScreent()
        }
    }
```

A method to change activity where you can pass your activity:

```
  private fun goToXScreen() {
        val intent = Intent(this, ABCActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Comment: i want to go Mainactivity to 2nd activity what i need to do

Comment: check edit, change ABCActivty with your activity and add this code in your MainActivity.

Comment: dont forget clickable and focusable attributes in your xml